If a body in free fall, according to general relativity is weightless, that is, not experiencing force, how does the object gain kinetic energy?
According to the classical Work-Energy theorem, force times distance equals the change in kinetic energy.  So, how is it in General Relativity that when a body falls to the ground the body gains kinetic energy even when there are no forces acting on it?  This seems to contradict the Work-Energy theorem.  And does this gain in kinetic energy have anything to do with time in General Relativity?

Why are you applying a "classical" theorem to GR in the first place.  Why would you even expect it to make sense?

Except for relativistic corrections the gain in energy from the viewpoint of an EXTERNAL observer (at infinity) is the same in GR as in Newtonian physics. Why is that? Because such an external observer can extract energy from the gravitating system. A simple example of such a mechanism are the weights in a grandfather clock. Nature doesn't do it that way, of course, it does it via friction in accretion disks and thermal (and often x-ray) radiation.

@FlatterMann Oops, I think you accidently typed in the comment box instead of an answer

@BioPhysicist My last serious run-in with general relativity was an oral exam in my third or forth year... many decades ago, so I feel a little intimidated to write an actual answer. I am flattered that the general direction of my comment seems to have found some appreciation, though. Thank you.

The answer box is where answers are written.

None of the answers actual contain the insight contained in the comments!

As Albertus Magnus mentioned, speed (and hence kinetic energy) is relative. From the point of view of the free falling object its energy is constant. An observer on Earth's surface, however, is constantly being accerated upwards (balanced by their tendency to fall back), so they are in an non-inertial frame of reference. This complicates things considerably.
If instead we take the point of view of a distant observer, also free-falling but so far away that they are effectively motionless, then the increasing kinetic energy of the falling object (the one closer to Earth) is due to the curvature of spacetime. This is because energy and momentum form a vector, with energy as the time component and ordinary 3-momentum as the spatial components. As the object moves through curved spacetime, the coordinates of its 4-momentum vector change. An analogy is to take a tall building on Earth and put it on a trailer. As the trailer moves over the horizon, the tall building will seem to get shorter: due to the curvature of the Earth, x and y coordinates of the top of the building are constantly changing relative to the "stationary" observer.
So your intuition that the energy increase is related to time is correct: energy is the temporal component of momentum, and as the object moves along a "curved" path its momentum temporal and spatial components get mixed. The details of the mixing are different in spacetime as opposed to the curved surface of the Earth (the geometry is different) but the basic principle is similar.

Just to  make a point speed may be relative but acceleration isnt.

@safesphere proper acceleration (what's measured by an accelerometer) is an invariant and is not relative

@EricSmith Is that different than someone saying "time intervals are relative" and replying with "proper time is invariant and not relative"?

@BioPhysicist There is a real sense in which "acceleration is absolute" whereas velocity is always relative. This is a distinction which trips up many beginners, e.g. it's the whole reason the twin paradox seems paradoxical. Safesphere's statement isn't exactly wrong, but I wanted to add the caveat for the benefit of beginners reading the comments.

@safesphere you're certainly moving through spacetime. And your accelerometer is showing 9.8 m/s^2 or thereabouts, because the Earth's surface is exerting force  to divert you from the geodesic you would otherwise follow.

@safesphere why don't you look at it and tell us?

I will have to look deeper into the meaning of the momentum-energy 4 vector.  Minkowski  was right when he said our reality will now have to include a merging of time and space.

@safesphere I am afraid Eric Smith is right. The accelerometer would show 9.81 m/s^2. Please read this.

@safesphere I think everyone is saying the same thing here, e.g. my example where the time interval between two events can be relative, but proper time is not relative, since it specifies a reference frame. I think that is all Eric was saying about the accelerometer as well

@safesphere So he is not wrong about accelerometer at least. I also think the problem lies in the notion of "relativ" which is ill defined. The relation "A moves relative to B" is not an equivalence relation in contrary to the relation "A rests relative to B" which is an equivalence relation dividing the set of all systems of reference into disjoint classes.

@safesphere We violently agree that (coordinate) acceleration is relative. What I was trying to emphasize is that there is a frame-independent sense in which an observer can be said to be "accelerated" (deviating from a geodesic). In this sense acceleration is "absolute". MTW devote a whole chapter (Chapter 6) to the subject of "Accelerated Observers", so that is certainly a thing in relativity. The distinction is subtle and probably not worth hashing out in the comment section, except to note that the laws of physics have a particularly simple form for unaccelerated observers.

Whether or not the object is "weightless" depends on frame of reference. For example, in an inertial frame of reference, an object in free fall certainly experiences a force by virtue of which it gains kinetic energy. On the other hand, in a non-inertial frame (one accelerating with the object) the object experiences no force and does not gain any kinetic energy at all, i.e. it remains at rest. This thought experiment is a good illustration of the generalized relativity principle, i.e. that non-inertial reference frames are indistinguishable from gravitational fields. The thing to remember is that motion is relative as opposed to absolute.

I agree that "motion is relative". But the OP is specifically asking in the context of general relativity, and there it's the free falling body that is inertial, not the "stationary" observer (who is the one that must accelerate)

@EricSmith well that's the problem. OP is treating the object with a GR view, and the frame via Newton (or Galileo?)--so there's a clash.

There are a couple of possible ‘aha!’ opportunities here.
The dynamically important quantity here is not really ‘energy’, but ‘energy-momentum’ (what MTW rather cutely call ‘momenergy’), which is a quantity which combines (classical) energy and (classical) momentum in a frame-independent way.  What ‘frame independent’ means is that everyone can calculate/measure/observe the same value for this, no matter what reference frame they're in.  It's a 4-d vector.  Different observers, however, calculate different components of this vector depending on the frame they're in (just as different observers would observe different x/y/z components of ordinary 3-momentum, depending on what direction they're facing).
If you're in a lift cabin falling to the ground, then you're in free fall.  You're not moving, nothing is changing (you can only tell you're ‘moving’ if you look out of a window, and get a nasty shock).  Specifically, your energy-momentum isn't changing.
An observer standing on the ground watching your fall (and presumably alarmed for your safety) measures the same value of the energy-momentum of the lift cabin – it's a frame independent thing.  But that observer is in a different frame from you, and so observes different values of the time component of this energy-momentum (which turns out to be related to the classical energy) and space components (which are related to classical momentum).  Thus you and this observer disagree about the components of this energy-momentum vector: specifically, you disagree about how much ‘energy’ there is in your motion.
Since the ground observer is accelerating (insert various quibbles here), the momentary (SR) inertial frame that they're in keeps changing, so their measurement of the time component of your E-M vector (ie, the ~classical energy) continually changes.  That is the ‘increase in kinetic energy’ that you're concerned about.
Short version: it's energy-momentum that's the important thing when thinking about motion in GR; the KE we're familiar with, and aim to build intuition with, is an observer-dependent detail of this, and different people will measure different values of this depending on how they're moving.

Thanks for this answer.  I suspected this paradox would be resolved by understanding 4 vectors, particularly, the momentum 4 vector, and that it would be related to the time component.  This is deep stuff.  Energy is somehow related to time.  I will have to ponder this for awhile.

The work energy theorem requires the second law $\vec F = m\vec a$. If we allow accelerations without a net force it is not valid.
Even without GR, it is possible to analyse the orbital motion (the fall of an object is a truncated orbital motion) without using force. We can look at the gravitational equation of a body in orbit: $$\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2} = -\frac{GM\hat r}{r^2}$$ only as a rule of dependence of the acceleration from the position. The Newton-Cartan theory follows this approach.

"...when a body falls to the ground the body gains kinetic energy even when there are no forces acting on it?"
If there were no forces acting on it, it would not be "falling". If it is falling (eg under gravity), then there are forces acting. General Relativity does not stop Newtons Laws from operating normally, it just explains what happens near the extremes.
A body in "free fall" simply means that the sum of all forces acting on that body are balanced, the obvious example being a satellite in orbit that is always 'falling' under gravity with constant acceleration resulting in constant velocity change but since it never gets closer to the earth, its kinetic energy remains constant.

Three down votes (so far). No comments explaining why. Not good behaviour.
